# It is a hashmap, using linear probing on an array

Tags: c++, hash-map

I have been studying hashtable for two days and was musterring up the courage to write a code. Finally I have written code in which I have taken many shortcuts:

1. The first being I have used compression function as key % hash_size;
2. I have not used any hashing function.
3. I have implemented it using array. A better option could be a vector.
4. For linear probing I have choose to store in the next empty index.
5. My code is not commented but is pretty straightforward.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
class data{
  private:
    int key;
    int value;
    bool deleteme;
  friend class hashtable;
};
class hashtable{
  public:
    hashtable(int m);
    hashtable(const hashtable& that);
    hashtable & operator= (hashtable src);
    ~hashtable();
    void add(int key, int value);
    bool exists(int key);
    int get(int key);
    void remove(int key);
    void display();
  private:
    int size;
    data* array;
};
hashtable::hashtable(int m):size(m){
    array = new data[m]();
    // data array[] = {NULL};
}
hashtable::hashtable(const hashtable& that){
  size = that.size;
  array = new data[that.size];
  for(int i = 0; i < that.size ; ++i){
    array[i] = that.array[i];
  }
}
hashtable & hashtable::operator=(hashtable src){
    std::swap(array, src.array);
    std::swap(size, src.size);
    return *this;
}
hashtable::~hashtable(){
    delete [] array;
}
void hashtable::add(int k, int val){
  int index = k % size;
  while(array[index].key != 0 || array[index].deleteme == 1){
    if(array[index].key == k)
      break;
    index += 1;
  }
  array[index].key = k;
  array[index].value = val;
}
bool hashtable::exists(int key){
  int index = key % size;
  while((array[index].key != key && index < size ) || (array[index].deleteme == 1 && index < size)){
    index += 1;
  }
  return index < size;
}
int hashtable::get(int key){
  int index = key % size;
  while((array[index].key != key && index < size) || (array[index].deleteme == 1 && index < size)){
    index += 1;
  }
  if(index < size)
    return array[index].value;
}
void hashtable::remove(int key){
  int index = key % size;
  while((array[index].key != key && index < size)|| (array[index].deleteme == 1 && index < size)){
    index += 1;
  }
  array[index].key = 0;
  array[index].value = 0;
  array[index].deleteme = 1;
}
void hashtable::display(){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        cout << array[i].key << " " << array[i].value  << " " << array[i].deleteme << endl;
    }
}

int main(){
  hashtable h1(11);
  h1.add(3,134);
  h1.add(14,139);
  h1.add(742,963);
  h1.add(11,456);
  h1.add(22,635);
  h1.add(33,852);
  h1.add(44,968);
  h1.add(9,589);
  h1.add(9,7890);
  h1.remove(14);
  h1.remove(33);
  h1.add(55,786);
  h1.add(10,56);
  cout << h1.get(44) << endl;
  // cout << h1.(43) << endl;
  h1.display();
}
```

Comment: Your code has multiple instances of undefined behavior. `key % size` could become negative, and you must not read `array[size]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `unsigned int` for the keys/hashes.
2. Make functions like `get`, `display` or `exists` const, so you make clear that they are not modifying the map and you can pass the map as `const&` to a function, which may uses this functions but does not use `add` or `remove` or other functions modifying the map.

   ```
   void display() const;
   ```
3. You can add `operator[]` which returns a reference to the value, here are the signatures:

   ```
   int& operator[](int key); // this can be used for assignment (``map[3] = 5``) and to get a value (``std::cout << map[3] << '\n'``). This needs to insert an element, if there is no element with the key and initialize its value to a default value like ``int()``/``0``
   int operator[](int key) const; // this is used when the map is accessed when it is const. No need for reference, but for other value-types like std::string, use std::string const& to avoid copying
   ```
4. You can make the class generic, to allow other value-types.
5. Make whitespace after each function or class, to seperate.